# Select all rows between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor, between

I have a `#tmp` table that looks like the following. It has a total of three lines.

| title | receipt_date | decision_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "It wasn't as bad as I thought it would be" | 2017-06-12 15:07:10.893 | 2017-06-23 09:37:31.667 |
| "It wasn't as bad as I thought it would be" | 2017-07-11 10:35:24.337 | 2018-06-25 05:54:41.133 |
| "It wasn't as bad as I thought it would be" | 2017-09-25 14:06:18.670 | 2017-11-21 05:13:08.563 |

The code is supposed to iterate through each of the three lines, and (based on the current iterated line) select all rows from the entire table where `receive_date` is between `receive_date` and `decision_date` on any other line.

NOTE: I specifically used greater-than and less-than (versus greater-than-or-equal) so that the row would not self select.

NOTE: `2017-09-25 14:06:18.670` is later than `2017-07-11 10:35:24.337` but earlier than  `2018-06-25 05:54:41.133`, so that line should return in the select. But I get nothing from the select.

I'm running the code in SSMS

CODE

```
SET @Cur2 = CURSOR FOR
  SELECT title,receipt_date,decision_date  
From #tmpTable
GROUP BY title,receipt_date,decision_date 
ORDER BY receipt_date

OPEN @Cur2
FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur2 INTO @TITLE,@RECEIPT_DATE,@DECISION_DATE;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  select *  
  from #tmpTable
  where receipt_date > @RECEIPT_DATE 
  AND   receipt_date < @DECISION_DATE

  FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur2 INTO @RECEIPT_DATE,@DECISION_DATE;
END;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have chosen to use a cursor to loop through the records instead of just selecting the records that match the criteria?

Comment: If there's a way to just select the rows without looping, that's great. It's just that the values of RECEIPT_DATE and DECISION_DATE are not known in advance. They're within the table itself. I.e. Submissions are supposed to be sequential, without two ever being in consideration at the same time. So, I need to examine all three rows, and determine if any submission was happening at the same time that any other submission was still in consideration.

Comment: For more explanation: Row one was submitted on June 12 2017, and rejected on June 23, 2017. Row two was submitted on July 11, 2017 and not rejected until June 25, 2018 ... HOWEVER, row three was submitted on Nov. 25, 2017 - which would have been while row two was still under consideration. This submission (row 3) should be flagged, because it should not have been submitted until after June 25, 2018. I.e. it was submitted between July 11, 2017  and June 25, 2018

Comment: An inner join would work, see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d801bff5b52b1f008a38c41bfee206f9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so easy to decipher your question. You should have posted a proper [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! But from what I get, it sounds like you could simply use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT *
       FROM #tmp t1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM #tmp t2
                            WHERE t2.receipt_date < t1.receipt_date
                                  AND t2.decision_date >= t1.receipt_date);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b3b0578bdf0764123f31db2bbc58e23e)